# Problem with function not recognising a similarity in two lists

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a piece of code that will print something if a similarity is found in between two lists so that I can later implement this into a sentence splitter. However I am having difficulty analysing one list to see if it containts elements of another list.

The code below shows what I have currently tried:

```
    sentence= "Hello. My name is George... Michael! David Browns. alittlemouse"
    exception_1_3_char = [". a", ". b", ". c", ". d", ". e", ". f", ". g", ". h", ". i", ". j", ". k", ". l", ". m", ". n", ". o", ". p", ". q", ". r", ". s", ". t", ". u", ". v", ". w", ". x", ". y", ". z"]
    def exception_finder(target_sentence):
        target_sentence = list(target_sentence)
        for character in range(len(exception_1_3_char)):
            if character in target_sentence:
                print("Exception Found")
    exception_finder(sentence)
```

Current Result:

No output at all.

Desired Result:

```
    Exception Found
```

Comment: try `for character in exception_1_3_char:` instead. Currently `character` is a number since you're iterating a range. You can also use a debugger to step through and see it, or just print the value of character. Also, since its a string (more than one character) - I'd call it "string" or "chars".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to not turn the `sentence` into a list, and also just iterate through the characters in `exception_1_3_char` (what you were doing with `range(len())` was iterating through `0, 1, ..., 25`).

```
sentence= "Hello. My name is George... Michael! David Browns. alittlemouse"
exception_1_3_char = [". a", ". b", ". c", ". d", ". e", ". f", ". g", ". h", ". i", ". j", ". k", ". l", ". m", ". n", ". o", ". p", ". q", ". r", ". s", ". t", ". u", ". v", ". w", ". x", ". y", ". z"]
def exception_finder(target_sentence):
    for character in exception_1_3_char:
        if character in target_sentence:
            print("Exception Found")
exception_finder(sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
for segment in exception_1_3:
    if segment in sentence:
       print("Exception found")
```